# Use Jinja2 to compare 2 items within the same list

Tags: ansible

Seeking for help here what would the jinja2 filter look like if i want to compare 2 list items? example: i want to filter out only records where host = dnsname

```
server_list:
   - { host: server1, dnsname: server1.acme.com }
   - { host: server2, dnsname: server2.acme.com }
   - { host: server3, dnsname: server3 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) will do the job. The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    server_list2: "{{ server_list|json_query('[?host==dnsname]') }}"
- debug:
    var: server_list2
```

give

```
"server_list2": [
    {
        "dnsname": "server3", 
        "host": "server3"
    }
]
```